# i cant use hooks in react,advice?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm building a react app and when i started with my first hook function I got this error

```
react-dom.development.js:16227 
        
       Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:16227:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at MenuWrapper (menuWrapper.jsx:16:1)
    at MenuList.jsx:12:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MenuList (MenuList.jsx:8:1)
    at Menu.render (menu.jsx:108:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
react-dom.development.js:18687 
        
       The above error occurred in the <Menu> component:

    at Menu (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:385:5)
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62087:78)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
react-dom.development.js:26923 
        
       Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:16227:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at MenuWrapper (menuWrapper.jsx:16:1)
    at MenuList.jsx:12:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MenuList (MenuList.jsx:8:1)
    at Menu.render (menu.jsx:108:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "jonathan",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "airbnb-prop-types": "^2.16.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "create-webpack-config": "^0.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-accordion": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-onclickout": "^2.0.8",
    "react-outside-click-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^6.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-script-tag": "^1.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "type-fest": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Finally, the .jsx page that I used the usestate.

```
 import React, { useState }from "react";
    
    import Area from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
    import City from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
    import Country from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
    import Neighborhood from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
    import Region from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as AreaW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as CityW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as CountryW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as  NeighborhoodW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as  RegionW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";
    
    
    export function MenuWrapper(type,id,isEdit){
   let [edit,setEdit] = useState(isEdit);
    if(isEdit){
       if(type==='country'){
            return(  
                     <div>
                        <div className={edit ? 'd-block' :'d-none'}><CountryW id={id}/><button onclick={() => setEdit=false}>read</button></div>
                        <div className={edit ? 'd-none' : 'd-block'}><Country id={id} /><button onclick={() => setEdit=true}>edit</button></div>
                     </div>
                     );
       }
       else{return(<div></div>)}
    }
    else{return(<div></div>)}
    
}
```

sorry, this is so long. please note I tried deleting the package_lock,json and node modules. then I tried npm start and even added a --force.that didn't resolve the issue.

For where I called it

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { MenuWrapper } from "./menuWrapper.jsx";
export function MenuList(Items,kind){
    if(Items===null){
        return(<div></div>)
    }
    return(
        <div>
           
                {
                   Items.map((item)=>{
                        return(
                            MenuWrapper(kind,item.id,false)
                        )
                    })
                
                }
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `MenuWrapper` does not look like a react component. Show us how and where do you use it.

Answer (score 3):

`hooks` can be called only within *react components*. `MenuWrapper` **is not** a react component (you are not invoking it as `<MenuWrapper />`).

You should use it as a component:

```
return (
    <MenuWrapper kind={kind} id={item.id} ...otherProps />
);
```

and then:

```
export function MenuWrapper({ kind, id, isEdit }) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you your advice worked.